# HAML nested IF conditions not working correctly in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

With the code below I am trying to only execute the @dataload_manuals.each if there are @dataload_manuals results.

When this runs in an account with no @dataload_manuals there are no errors. However, for an account with @dataload_manuals I get the error below.

Also, if I remove the if @dataload_manuals line the account with @dataload_manuals shows correctly.

What is the correct way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance for any advice.

HAML from my view:

```
%table
  %tr
    %th Connector
    %th User
    %th Last run
    - if @dataload_manuals
      - @dataload_manuals.each do |d|
        %tr
          %td Manual
          %td= d.user ? d.user.email : ''
          %td= d.updated_at
```

the error message I get:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for #<DataloadManual:0x00000003a31468>):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error it looks like @dataload_manuals isn't an array or active record relation, but a single instance of DataloadManual.  So your 'if' will be true, but it won't respond to 'each'.

Make sure that @dataload_manuals actually contains multiple records and responds to each.

Comment: How do I make it respond to each?

Comment: ok, so in the controller @dataload_logs was being defined as: DataloadLog.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).find_by_account_id(current_user.account_id) which throws an error when I run it in console. Is there a better way to return the records from DataloadLog scoped for the current_user.account_id?

Comment: Assuming your relationships are setup right, `current_user.account.dataload_logs.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page])`  (not sure if "logs" is a typo and should be "manuals" as it is in your question)

Comment: you are right, I was changing. I have two controllers with the same problem. the change you suggested returns an error of: undefined method `dataload_log'. While this versions works (other than it is not scoped to account) @dataload_logs = DataloadLog.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]). Any suggestions on how I should change my approach?

Comment: I played with this a bit and got the following to work. Thanks for all your help.     @dataload_logs = DataloadLog.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).find_all_by_account_id(current_user.account_id)

Answer (score 0):

`@dataload_manuals` appears to be an instance of `DataloadManual` and not an enumerable so there is nothing to iterate on.